# Why is findIndex() returning -1 here?

Tags: javascript

```js
if(e.target.className === "deleteNode") {
        console.log(e.target.parentNode);
        let index = allNodes.findIndex(el => {
            console.log("E: "+e.target.parentNode.lastChild.innerHTML);
            console.log("El: "+el.lastChild.innerHTML);
            console.log("compare: "+el.lastChild.innerHTML.localeCompare(e.target.parentNode.lastChild.innerHTML));
            el.lastChild.innerHTML.localeCompare(e.target.parentNode.lastChild.innerHTML))
        });
        console.log("index: "+index);
```

The above is called from a click listener. Click happens on a button inside a dynamically created div element. The last child of the div is a <p> node. I want to get the index of the first match for the value of the text inside that div. allNodes is an array declared at the top of the script.

I have tried using the === comparator but same result. The 2 strings are identical but findIndex() is failing (returning -1)

console output for the above segment below
[image]

Comment: it's cz you are not returning anything from function

Comment: i did not close the issue ... and return is not automatic. if you use curly braces then you have to return if you are using round brackets it's auto return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no auto return from arrow functions when you use `{}` like that. You have to use the `return` statement.

```
if(e.target.className === "deleteNode") {
        console.log(e.target.parentNode);
        let index = allNodes.findIndex(el => {
            console.log("E: "+e.target.parentNode.lastChild.innerHTML);
            console.log("El: "+el.lastChild.innerHTML);
            console.log("compare: "+el.lastChild.innerHTML.localeCompare(e.target.parentNode.lastChild.innerHTML));
            return el.lastChild.innerHTML.localeCompare(e.target.parentNode.lastChild.innerHTML))
        });
        console.log("index: "+index);
```